# How to delete the header from introduction chapter?

Tags: chapters

I write a report and I want to write an introduction before the first chapter,so I put this at the begin of "Introduction file":

```
\chapter*{Introduction générale} \label{Introdution}
```

I have 3 pages in the introduction.The problem that I got [image: introduction] in the second and the third page.how delete this from these pages.

Comment: can you please add a minimale example of your code?

Comment: try `\chapter*{Introduction générale}\markboth{Introdution}{Introdution}` you don't need `\label` because there is no number here.